# Add QName as string to @XmlMixed@XmlAnyElement(lax = true) list

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Sorry for the foggy title, I know it does not tell much.

Please consider the following xsd type definition:

```
    <xsd:complexType name="TopicExpressionType" mixed="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="Dialect" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required"/>
        <xsd:anyAttribute/>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Complete XSD: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd

Corresponding JAXB generated Java class:

```
package org.oasis_open.docs.wsn.b_2;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TopicExpressionType", propOrder = {
        "content"
})
public class TopicExpressionType {
    
    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> content;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Dialect", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String dialect;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    public List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    public String getDialect() {
        return dialect;
    }

    public void setDialect(String value) {
        this.dialect = value;
    }

    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }
}
```

The first goal is to produce an XML like this with JAXB:

```
<wsnt:TopicExpression Dialect="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/Concrete" xmlns:tns="http://my.org/TopicNamespace">
tns:t1/*/t3
</wsnt:TopicExpression>
```

Please note the followings:

- The value of the `TopicExpression` element is basically a query string that refers to QNames. Example: `tns:t1/*/t3`
- The value of the `TopicExpression` element contains one or more QName like strings (`tns:t1`). It must be a string as in the example, it cannot be an Element (e.g.: `<my-expresseion>tns:t1/*/t3<my-expresseion/>`)
- The value of the `TopicExpression` element is an arbitrary string (at least from the schema's perspective, it follows the rules defined here: https://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/wsn-ws_topics-1.3-spec-os.pdf page 18)
- Even though the value is a string, I need to define the corresponding name space declarations. So if I have an expression like this:
  `tns:t1` then `xmlns:tns` has to be declared. If my expresseion is `tns:t1/*/tns2:t3` then both `xmlns:tns` and `xmlns:tns2` have to be declared.

The second goal is to get the value of `TopicExpression` on the other side together with the namespace, using JAXB.

I am completely stuck, I don't know how I could implement this. My only idea is to manually build the value for the `TopicExpression` and somehow tell the marshaller to include the related namespace declaration despite there is no actual element using it.

**Update**
Example for a complete SOAP request that includes the before mentioned `TopicExpression`:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:Header>
        <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/bw-2/NotificationProducer/SubscribeRequest</Action>
        <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:57182d32-4e07-4f5f-8ab3-24838b3e33ac</MessageID>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ns3:Subscribe xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" >
            <ns3:ConsumerReference>
                <ns4:Address>http://my-notification-consumer-url</ns4:Address>
            </ns3:ConsumerReference>
            <ns3:Filter>
                <ns3:TopicExpression Dialect="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/Simple" xmlns:ns5="http://my.org/TopicNamespace" xmlns:ns6="http://extension.org/TopicNamespace">
                    ns5:t1/*/ns6:t3
                <ns3:TopicExpression/>
            </ns3:Filter>
        </ns3:Subscribe>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Try adding `namespace="http://my.org/TopicNamespace"` to the @XmlType

Comment: @LMC Unfortunately the namespace is not fixed, it changes at runtime so I cannot hardcode it.

Comment: If the schema is not permanent I would use normal JAXP / XML API instead of JAXB for this simple XML, or I would run an XSL transformation to a more standardized XML and would read that with JAXB.

Comment: @m4gic This is not the whole XML document of course, this is just the relevant part. I'll look into the XSL transformation, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, If I have understood your requirement correctly. See if this code sample is helpful for you. If not then maybe try to edit your question a bit and make me understand what exactly you are looking for. I will try to modify and update the code accordingly. Trying with a simple example would be better than providing the complete XSD. Also, look into the following methods: `beforeMarshal` and `afterUnmarshal`.

Following is the XML I am trying to marshal and unmarshal

```
<tns:TopicExpression Dialect="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/Concrete" xmlns:tns="http://my.org/TopicNamespace">
    tns:t1/*/t3
</tns:TopicExpression>
```

TopicExpressionType.class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestPojo {

    @XmlValue
    private String TopicExpression;

    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<String, Object> anyAttributes = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("topic.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestPojo.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final TestPojo topic = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, TestPojo.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(topic.toString());

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        Map<String, String> namespaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
        namespaces.put("http://my.org/TopicNamespace", "tns");
        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestPojo.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, namespaces);
        QName qName = new QName("http://my.org/TopicNamespace","TopicExpression","tns");
        JAXBElement<TestPojo> root = new JAXBElement<TestPojo>(qName, TestPojo.class, topic);
        marshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);
        String result = stringWriter.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

As you can see as of now I have populated the namespaces map directly. If this is dynamic then you can populate the same in a map and accordingly you can add it while marshaling.

This will provide the following output during the unmarshalling:

```
TestPojo(TopicExpression=
    tns:t1/*/t3
, anyAttributes={Dialect=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/Concrete})
```

During marshaling:

```
<tns:TopicExpression xmlns:tns="http://my.org/TopicNamespace" Dialect="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/Concrete">
    tns:t1/*/t3
</tns:TopicExpression>
```

Comment: The `TopicExpression` element shall not contain child elements, like `<google:field1>Value1</google:field1>`. It is expected to contain the above specified string, which is a query expression defined in the ws-topics doc (linked above)
If I could add actual Elements to the TopicExpression that would be very nice and easy to implement.

Comment: @bakcsa83 ok, I have edited my answer and code sample to match your XML. Now check.

Comment: Now in your solution the `TopicExpression` element has the same name space as its value (tns). This is wrong.  
The `TopicExpression` has its own name space which is `wsnt` in my question.
Also please note that the expression value might have multiple QNames (4th bullet point in the question.).

Comment: But I don't see any declared namespace for `wsnt`. If you have used the prefix `wsnt` then it should be declared within the parent XML element of within itself. I do not see any namespace corresponding to  `wsnt`.  I validated your XML and got the result as `The prefix "wsnt" for element "wsnt:TopicExpression" is not bound.`. If you have the namespace corresponding to it then you can add it to the Map before marshaling and use it that should not be an issue I believe.

Comment: It wast not there because its value is not relevant and I did not want to bring in the whole context (SOAP, Spring etc.)
The point is that the TopicExpression element is in different name space than the value (tns:t1).

Comment: Adding the namespace prefixes of the values (`tns`) to the Map does not help because the marshaller uses that map only if it recognizes the usage of the listed namespaces in the object to be marshalled. Since the "`tns:t1/*/t3`" value is not something the marshaller recognizes, it does not know either that the `tns` part is actually a prefix to be resolved and wont use the namespace prefix mapper. That's the core of the porblem.

Comment: Marshaller will not recognize the usage of the namespaces if you add it to the `Map`. Irrespective of whether the namespaces in Map are used or not in XML it will add it to the Marshalled XML. I am not understanding your requirement correctly `tns:t1/*/t3` is a value for the XML node `tns:TopicExpression` why are you relating it with the Namespace? in XML it would be treated as value.

Comment: "Irrespective of whether the namespaces in Map are used or not in XML it will add it to the Marshalled XML" 
That does not seem to be true, at least not in my environment. (I use org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.4). Namespaces that are present in the map but not in the object to be marshalled will not be added to the xml.

Comment: "why are you relating it with the Namespace? in XML it would be treated as value"
Very good question. Because that's what the ws-topics standard dictates and it is also an explicit requirement from the customer. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I've implemented:

Created a new `TopicExpressionType` class which has fields not only for the expression but for the namespaces too, used in the expression:

```
public class TopicExpressionType {
    String dialect;
    String expression;
    List<Namespace> namespaces;

    public TopicExpressionType(String dialect, String expression, List<Namespace> namespaces) {
        this.dialect = dialect;
        this.expression = expression;
        this.namespaces = namespaces;
    }

    public static class Namespace {
        String prefix;
        String namespace;

        public Namespace(String prefix, String namespace) {
            this.prefix = prefix;
            this.namespace = namespace;
        }

        public String getPrefix() {
            return prefix;
        }

        public String getNamespace() {
            return namespace;
        }
    }
}
```

Then implemented an `XmlAdapter` that is aware of the specifics, knows how to extract namespace prefixes from the expression string and it can read/write namespace declarations on the TopicExpression XML element:

```
public class TopicExpressionTypeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Element, TopicExpressionType> {

    @Override
    public Element marshal(TopicExpressionType topicExpression) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();
        Element element = document.createElementNS("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2", "mns1:TopicExpression");
        element.setAttribute("Dialect", topicExpression.getDialect());

        element.setTextContent(topicExpression.getExpression());
        for (var ns : topicExpression.namespaces) {
            element.setAttribute("xmlns:" + ns.prefix, ns.namespace);
        }

        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public TopicExpressionType unmarshal(Element arg0) throws Exception {
        if (arg0.getFirstChild() instanceof Text text) {
            var expression = text.getData();
            if (expression == null || expression.isBlank())
                throw new TopicExpressionAdapterException("Empty content");

            // Extract the prefixes from the expression
            var namespacePrefixes = new ArrayList<String>();
            getNamespacePrefixes(expression, namespacePrefixes);

            //Now get the namespaces for the prefixes
            var nsMap = new ArrayList<TopicExpressionType.Namespace>();
            for (var prefix : namespacePrefixes) {
                var namespace = arg0.getAttribute("xmlns:" + prefix);
                if (namespace == null || namespace.isBlank())
                    throw new TopicExpressionAdapterException("Missing namespace declaration for the following prefix: " + prefix);
                nsMap.add(new TopicExpressionType.Namespace(prefix, namespace));
            }

            var dialect = arg0.getAttribute("Dialect");

            if (dialect == null || dialect.isBlank())
                throw new TopicExpressionAdapterException("Missing Dialect attribute");

            return new TopicExpressionType(dialect, expression, nsMap);
        } else {
            throw new TopicExpressionAdapterException("Unexpected child element type: " + arg0.getFirstChild().getClass().getName());
        }

    }

    public static class TopicExpressionAdapterException extends Exception {
        public TopicExpressionAdapterException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Implementation of the `getNamespacePrefixes()` method is left out intentionally from this answer.

The last step is to add the following annotation wherever the TopicExpressionType is used in JAXB generated classes:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TopicExpressionTypeAdapter.class)
TopicExpressionType topicExpression;
```